# connection one time to network Drive when Creating files with Impersonator

Tags: c#, impersonation, network-drive

I have to create many files in Network drive with specified user.

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716117/replace-current-windows-user-running-the-exe-with-another-user) to connect different user 
I use Impersonator Class :

```
public class Impersonator : IDisposable
{

    const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

    private IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
    private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonated;
    private readonly string _ErrMsg = "";

    public bool IsImpersonating
    {
        get { return (token != IntPtr.Zero) && (impersonated != null); }
    }

    public string ErrMsg
    {
        get { return _ErrMsg; }
    }

    [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    public Impersonator(string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        StopImpersonating();

        bool loggedOn = LogonUser(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token);
        if (!loggedOn)
        {
            _ErrMsg = new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception().Message;
            return;
        }

        WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(token);
        impersonated = identity.Impersonate();
    }

    private void StopImpersonating()
    {
        if (impersonated != null)
        {
            impersonated.Undo();
            impersonated = null;
        }

        if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            CloseHandle(token);
            token = IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        StopImpersonating();
    }
}
```

and the code :

```
using (Impersonator impersonator = new Impersonator("UserName", "UserPwd", "UserDomaine"))
{
    if (!Directory.Exists("Z:\\")) // check if Network drive exist
    {
       NetworkDrive drive = new NetworkDrive
       {
           ShareName = @"\\IP\Partage",
           LocalDrive = "Z",
           Force = true
       };

       drive.MapDrive(@"UserDomaine\UserName", "UserPwd");

     }
     File.Create(@"Z:\Log\FileName.txt");
}
```

But in this case I found that the code Map the drive every time that I have to create a file or update it!! And I have a lot of work with this function.

There’s a solution to not map it every time?

I tried to Map the driver in with this user in opening of application but same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't need to map the drive. After impersonating you can just create the file directly using the network drive and it will create the file as impersonated user.

```
using (Impersonator impersonator = new Impersonator("UserName", "UserPwd", "UserDomaine"))
{
    File.Create(@"\\IP\Partage\Log\FileName.txt");
}
```

Comment: From the server can you try accessing the path from the windows explorer logging in as one of the users?

Comment: I test this in local it work (I have to implimente this in the project and send it to the server production and tell you the result

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use Using block. declare Impersonator as global static variable.

Comment: without using will not use the newuser